# Fill row where foreign key is null with new inserted data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to update rows from a table where the foreign key is null with newly inserted row :

This is what I am trying to do but it doesn't work. I have seen the with and merge keyword but don't understand them. Can you help me ?
I could do that with a for loop in my function but maybe better solution can be found.

The DB is with Postgresql.
Thanks

```sql
update quotation_request qr
set qr.negotiation_id = (insert into negotiation n default values returning n.id)
from negotiation n 
where qr.negotiation_id is null;
```

Comment: You've answered this yourlself - for loop is necessary. You'll need to insert, get the id, then update. Also, your update doesn't need that `from`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't embed an `INSERT` statement directly inside the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE` statement. What you can do is using a `cte`, something like this :

```
    WITH list AS
    (  SELECT *
         FROM quotation_request AS qr
        WHERE qr.negotiation_id IS NULL
      FOR UPDATE
    ), insert_list AS
    (  INSERT INTO negotiation VALUES (...)
       SELECT (... default_values ...)
        FROM list AS l
       RETURNING id, columns_as_foreign_key
    )
    UPDATE quotation_request qr
       SET negotiation_id = l.id
      FROM list AS l
     WHERE gr.foreign_key_columns = l.columns_as_foreign_key
```